# YouTube API V3 Video Format

Tags: youtube-api

Previously in V2 we could get video format with values: 1,5,6.

The format parameter, which is supported for video search requests, specifies that videos must be available in at least one of the video formats listed in the parameter value. Your request can specify one or more of the following formats:

1 - RTSP streaming URL for mobile video playback. H.263 video (up to 176x144) and AMR audio.

5 - HTTP URL to the embeddable player (SWF) for this video. This format is not available for a video that is not embeddable. Developers commonly add &format=5 to their queries to restrict results to videos that can be embedded on their sites.

6 - RTSP streaming URL for mobile video playback. MPEG-4 SP video (up to 176x144) and AAC audio.

How can we get these same values from v3 of the API? I have looked through the videos-list call and have not found any similar parameter. I am trying to find this information on videos which I do not own.

Comment: I believe this feature was depreciated and not replaced, but I don't see anything in the Deprecations section of the [Implementation and Migration guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/deprecated).